# wp8 isloated storage or sqlite

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage

i've created a windows phone 8 app, that is giving the result of calculations at runtime,
now i need to store that result for future use/access,

what to do?

i have totally no idea of storage in wp8, although i've seen many tutorials for isolated storage & sqlite, but did'nt understood whats going on in them......

any suggestion? how to store my data..? easy steps to follow

this is the code, which is showing result on a page at runtime,

```
 protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        date.Text = time.ToShortDateString();
        for (int i = 0; i < NavigationContext.QueryString.Count; i++)
        {
            KeyValuePair<string, string> kv = NavigationContext.QueryString.ElementAt(i);

            StackPanel panel = new StackPanel();
            TextBlock block1 = new TextBlock();
            TextBlock block2 = new TextBlock();
            block1.Text = kv.Key;
            block2.Text = kv.Value;
            block1.Width = 100;
            block2.Width = 100;
            panel.Orientation = System.Windows.Controls.Orientation.Horizontal;
            panel.Height = 50;
            panel.Children.Add(block1);
            panel.Children.Add(block2);
            ContentPanel.Children.Add(panel);



        }


    }
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use it both if you want to see your database structure or instant insert and update or delete it than sqlite is best way...

Go thorough bellow link here is example of local daabase in windows phone 8 with sqlite.

[Windows Phone 7 Native Database Programming via Sqlite Client for Windows Phone](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/silverlight/Windows-Phone-7-Native-Database-Programming-via-Sqlite-Client-for-Windows-Phone.aspx)

[SQLite-WinRT: Database programming on Windows Phone and Windows 8](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andy_wigley/archive/2013/06/06/sqlite-winrt-database-programming-on-windows-phone-and-windows-8.aspx)

[How to use SQLite in Windows Phone](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_use_SQLite_in_Windows_Phone)

Hope it will help you